# Typescript + Jest (ts-jest) CommonJS / ESM configuration fail

Tags: typescript, react-native, jestjs, ts-jest

My [ts-jest](https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest) test of [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-based-navigation#minimal-example-of-tab-based-navigation) fails with the error:

```
yarn run v1.22.10
$ jest
FAIL __tests__/App.spec.tsx
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

    By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

    Here's what you can do:
     • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/en/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

    Details:

    /home/rct/cod/rn-testing-issue-github-example/node_modules/react-native-iphone-x-helper/index.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import { Dimensions, Platform, StatusBar } from 'react-native';
                                                                                             ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1350:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@react-navigation/bottom-tabs/lib/commonjs/views/SafeAreaProviderCompat.tsx:7:1)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.901 s
Ran all test suites.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

The app works as expected in the emulator but I can't get tests running. Obviously, some sort of CommonJS/ESM configuration incompatibility above my pay grade, but I've been unable to resolve it after following half a dozen different tutorials :(

All ideas welcome!

Same issue posted [in React Navigation issue tracker](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/9517).

To reproduce:

```
git clone https://github.com/githorse/rn-testing-issue-example.git
cd rn-testing-issue-example
yarn test
```

**App.tsx**
(copied from [React Navigation docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-based-navigation#minimal-example-of-tab-based-navigation)):

```
// App.tsx
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

function HomeScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function SettingsScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Settings!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

**App.spec.tsx**:

```
// __tests__/App.spec.tsx
import 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import App from '../App';

// Note: test renderer must be required after react-native.
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

jest.useFakeTimers();

it('renders correctly', () => {
  renderer.create(<App />);
});
```

**babel.config.js** from [ts-jest React Native docs](https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/guides/react-native/):

```
// babel.config.js
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
}
```

**jest.config.js** from [ts-jest React Native docs](https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/guides/react-native/), adding the `setupFiles` key referring to `jest.setup.js`:

```
// jest.config.js
const { defaults: tsjPreset } = require('ts-jest/presets')

module.exports = {
  ...tsjPreset,
  preset: 'react-native',
  transform: {
    ...tsjPreset.transform,
    '\\.js$': '<rootDir>/node_modules/react-native/jest/preprocessor.js',
  },
  globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
      babelConfig: true,
    },
  },
  // This is the only part which you can keep
  // from the above linked tutorial's config:
  cacheDirectory: '.jest/cache',
  setupFiles: [
    '<rootDir>/setup.jest.js' 
 ]
}
```

**setup.jest.js** from [React Native Mocking Native Modules example](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/testing/#mocking-native-modules), commenting out a line that produces another (presumably unrelated) error:

```
// setup.jest.js
import 'react-native-gesture-handler/jestSetup';
// import { cleanup } from '@testing-library/react-native';

jest.mock('react-native-reanimated', () => {
  const Reanimated = require('react-native-reanimated/mock');

  // The mock for `call` immediately calls the callback which is incorrect
  // So we override it with a no-op
  Reanimated.default.call = () => {};

  return Reanimated;
});

// Silence the warning: Animated: `useNativeDriver` is not supported because the native animated module is missing
// jest.mock('react-native/Libraries/Animated/src/NativeAnimatedHelper');

// As of react-native@0.64.X file has moved
jest.mock('react-native/Libraries/Animated/NativeAnimatedHelper');
```

Comment: As you can see, the module wasn't transpiled. It needs to be added to Jest's transformIgnorePatterns

Comment: @EstusFlask - adding `transformIgnorePatterns: [ 'node_modules/react-native-iphone-x-helper' ]` actually does resolve the above error. However, then I get a similar error about `node_modules/@react-navigation/bottom-tabs/lib/commonjs/views/SafeAreaProviderCompat.tsx`, and for some reason I can't get this one to resolve by adding the path in `transformIgnorePatterns`. But I just discovered that an *empty* `transformIgnorePatterns: []` seems to resolve all my issues and give me a passing test. So ... problem solved?

Comment: No, `[]` will force everything from node_modules to be transpiled, which is a mistake. transformIgnorePatterns are regexp strings and need to be properly escaped. There can be backslashes because paths are platform dependent. `node_modules/react-native-iphone-x-helper` is wrong because package path should NOT match in order to be transpiled, usually with `(?!` negative lookahead. See related questions regarding transformIgnorePatterns

Comment: Yes, just realizing that was backwards. I'm able to get it working with `node_modules/(?!(@react-native|react-native))` (without trailing slash) but that also seems a bit broad. So far I'm unable to use any more specific pattern. Still misunderstanding something here as including `node_modules/(?!(@react-native|react-native|@react-navigation)/)` does not resolve the same error when it now originates in `node_modules/@react-navigation/bottom-tabs/lib/commonjs/views/SafeAreaProviderCompat.tsx`.